# using requestmapping annotation to request page

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, spring-mvc, tomcat

I am using eclipse to write some spring MVC project, but my project can't find the variable of requestmapping I gave.
so I write some test controller to display my test.jsp

controller.java

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class test{
    @RequestMapping(value="test",method={RequestMethod.GET})
    public String test() {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

test.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=BIG5"
    pageEncoding="BIG5"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="BIG5">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h6>hello world!</h6>
</body>
</html>
```

Sadly,no matter how I've tried,my tomcat server just can't find the page by using the path
`http://localhost:(port)/(projectname)/test`

Eclipse version also confused me.I used to put my jsp beneath the webcontent/web-inf in old version of eclipse.However,after updating my eclipse to 2021-06 ,I'm not surely understand where should I put my jsp to enable my controller can get use of it.
[image]

I've found if I just put my jsp under my webapp folder,I could use absolute path to get my jsp

```
http://localhost:8080/acqdemo/test.jsp
```

However, It might no longer be as Spring MVC Framework anymore.Sorry to ask this simple question.
I'm a newbie of java spring, and I just hope anyone can help me solve this problem.

btw this is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="4.0">
  <display-name>acqdemo</display-name>
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>classpath:servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
  <absolute-ordering />
</web-app>
```

Comment: Define view resolvers to help MVC find the page.

Comment: It if was directly under the WEB-INF folder before, put it directly under the WEB-INF folder now. The project creation wizard also lets you enter the old WebContent path if you want, the default is just different now.

Comment: @Alien Hi,I've tried to put the view resolver bean in view.xml I created.I followed the example XmlViewResolver from Spring.io document.The tomcat server runs successfully, but my requestmapping annotation still not found.

Comment: @nitind so do you mean that I can use the old WebContent path to find my jsp in recent version? Or I still need to change the different path to get my resources?Thanks

Comment: You can use the old path in new projects if you want, but it what matters is that you treat everything under whatever path you use the same in either case. If you were supposed to add a jsp folder before, add it now. If not then, don't do it now.